# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8.5

There are quite a lot of threads and questions about this issue. However, non-of them helped me.

I have got an MVC4 app running on IIS8 without any probblem. I need to move this app to Windows 2012 R2 Server which has IIS8.5.

Whichever user I give access to folder, I still get following exception.

HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Most likely causes:

**The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.**

Here is the error trace screenshot
[image]

Regarding IIS Site Setup, Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication are enabled.

Lastly, I have given Server\IIS_USERS, App Pool Account, IUSR, Server\Users readn and write access to make it work, but still same error.

Could anyone help me with this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are creating a folder, not a web application to publish the solution.

Comment: It is a web application on the IIS...